# Sphinx4 Speech Recognition from a video

Tags: video, speech-recognition, video-processing, speech-to-text, sphinx4

Does Sphinx4 support Speech-to-Text processing on video files? If yes, Does it need JMF?
Is there any tutorials ??

I couldn't find anything, not in their [forum](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/forums/forum/382337), and nobody is responding in their [IRC Channel](http://irc://irc.freenode.net/#cmusphinx)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does Sphinx4 support Speech-to-Text
>   processing on video files?

Yes. There is no specifics of the video. You need to extract the audio track and pass it to recognizer.

> If yes, Does it need JMF?

There could be different way to extract audio track from the video. It can be JMF or just mplayer

> Is there any tutorials ??

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorial

Comment: Thank you, I thought I could find a way to handle the video directly, or to extend the AudioFileDataSource ...